# Create a bootable ubuntu Usb stick on Mac

Tags: usb, live-usb, mac

I have followed the instructions from various posts at the forum and I when I execute in the terminal

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m
```

then it requires the password but instead it does not let me type the password. If i press enter then the same thing until I repeat it three times which will require me to execute the above command again. Anyone knows why and how to solve it?

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx OR http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-drive-for-pc-on-a-mac--cms-21187

Answer (score 0):

Ok just to let you know I found the mistake. In the sudo line I did not specify the exact name of the usb and for some reason it was asking me for password which was basically useless as I said above.

I repeated the process with no mistakes and finally created the usb boot stick.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer, since it was the solution to the problem! :)